# Vectors in Tropical Arithmetic

Tags: linear-algebra, tropical-geometry

*Introduction to Tropical Geometry* states the following theorem about strongly-connected graphs and tropical eigenvalues:

> *Let A be an n × n-matrix such that G(A) is strongly connected. Then A has
> precisely one eigenvalue λ(A). It equals the minimum normalized length of a directed cycle.*

Considering some sample strongly-connected graph *B* with the corresponding matrix *M(B)*

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
4 & 1 \\
1 & 3 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Per the theorem, the sole eigenvalue of *M(B)* should be $(b_{1,2}+b_{2,1})/2 = 1$. However, what does the corresponding eigenvector mean graphically? What does any vector signify in this context?